# socket inputstread read() is blocked, but the thread is runing, how to understand it?

Tags: java, socket.io

socket inputstread read() is blocked due to no data received, but the thread is running, how to understand it?

what's the block's meaning and difference with thread block state?

Comment: I think he means the thread is alive.  A thread in a blocked state is actually still "alive", but is idle...

Comment: java split the thread to status: block, wait, sleep, running, etc, but socked inputstream read not belong to block, so my puzzle is how to hang thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the thread *isn't* running if it's blocked in read(). Do you mean it is 'RUNNABLE'? That just means it isn't blocked in a Java semaphore, and it is runnable as soon as the read() returns. It is waiting for data to arrive from the peer.

Comment: no, you can watch its thread status by java visualvm, it is running always.

Comment: @jiafu You've missed the point. 'Running' or 'RUNNABLE'? And *I* can't watch *your* visualvm.

Comment: I watch the visual vm again. in actual, the visual vm take the runnable and running both as running. So I misunderstand it. Thanks.

Comment: @jiafu That's nice but you still haven't answered the question.